# How to permanately fix a cd drive at a given location in winecfg

Tags: ubuntu, wine, winetricks

I'm brand new to linux, and I installed some CD based windows educational software in wine and it works great, except for some reason it can't find the disk unless I manually change the path from its default location G:/media/user/cdname/ to D:/media/user/cdname/, but this is reset back to G:/... every time I put in a new cd. Is there a way to permanently change this location to D?

This is on ubuntu 19.04 and wine 4.7

Comment: How did you change the path? Which drive letter signify which drive?

Comment: @Biswapriyo this is from the drive tab on winecfg.  It defaults to mapping the cd drive to G:/ and D:/ to nothing.  Mapping D:/ to the location works but it does not stay permanent, even if I delete the G:/ mapping altogether.  It just adds it in again